# Python - Remove text between two string of the same line

Tags: python

I have a file with text like below. I need to remove anything between "AS" and "$$" but keep those 2 words. The replacement should be for the same line and I dont need to check for multi lines as AS and $$ always are in the same line

```
AS '-1', $$ 
Some extra lines 1
some extra lines 2
AS '24:-1', $$ 
Some extra lines 3
some extra lines 4
AS 'abc-1', $$ 
Some extra lines 5
some extra lines 6
```

The output should be

```
AS $$ 
Some extra lines 1
some extra lines 2
AS $$ 
Some extra lines 3
some extra lines 4
AS $$ 
Some extra lines 5
some extra lines 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the lines and store them in a list:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = [line for line in f]
```

Then you can check whether the line contains 'AS' and '$$' and if it does you can write out 'AS $$', otherwise you write out the original line:

```
with open('txt.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in text:
        if 'AS' in t and '$$' in t:
            f.write('AS $$\n')
        else:
            f.write(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the lines and use `split` to get the first and last element from each line to determine if you want to write 'AS $$' or the original line in the new file:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as input_file:
   lines = input_file.readlines()
   with open("out.txt","w") as output_file:
      for line lines:
         line = line.strip() #remove newline character
         values = line.split() #break up line by spaces, so AS '-1', $$ becomes ['AS', '-1,', '$$]
         if values[0] == 'AS' and values[-1] == '$$':
            output_file.write('AS $$\n')
         else:
            output_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I can have some extra lines as well in between which I need those as well

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for what's between the 2 words you should just read how much lines you have and write "AA $$" for the number of lines x)

No need to complexify the problem !